# Does using Tor network in a commercial service make it a commercial use of Tor?

Tags: legal

I'm a developer and I'm thinking of using the Tor network (custom implementation of the spec.) in a commercial non-opensource service as a platform. I would like to know if my service which is based on the Tor network counts as based on Tor ? If so, should I contact Tor about this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks like you’re referring to the [FAQ page](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/trademark-faq). If so, it’s referring to the Tor *trademark* when it says “based on Tor”. If you’re using the name “Tor” anywhere in your commercial project, then yes it sounds like you should contact Tor.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add Steve's well-written comment as an answer for other users:

It looks like you’re referring to the [FAQ page](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/trademark-faq). If so, it’s referring to the Tor *trademark* when it says “based on Tor”. If you’re using the name “Tor” anywhere in your commercial project, then yes it sounds like you should contact Tor.